# Creating a video and audio stream with VLC

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, vlc, audio-streaming

I am trying to create an application which allows a client to screen share to the server with standard desktop audio, like in a discord call. How can I go about this with a C# VLC library or something equivalent.

For clarification, I am using LibVLCSharp and this is the arguments I have tried for the media

```
Media.AddOption(":screen-fps=24 :live-caching=0 :network-caching=0");
Media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8080/screenshare}");
```

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou, I have added clarification to my original post if this helps

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way.  Please feel free to edit your own question by clicking the **Edit** link above or by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70456137/edit).  There is no need to post below.  SO isn't like a _forum_.  Good luck!